# What exactly does "local identification" mean in the context of structural VARs and VECMs?

Tags: time-series, terminology, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model, identifiability

In Lutkepohl's ["New Introduction to Time Series Analysis"](http://www.afriheritage.org/TTT/2%20New%20Introduction%20to%20Multiple%20Time%20Series%20Analysis.pdf), chapter 9, this term is frequently mentioned, but is in no where well-defined. So what exactly does "local identification" mean in this context?